# Синонимичны ли глаголы «соответствовать» и «подходить»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, глаголы, синонимы

В чем отличие слов "соответствовать" и "подходить"?
Или в определенных ситуациях они могут выступать синонимами?
Например, *соответствовать текущей ситуации* = *подходить текущей ситуации*?

Answer (score 1):

Начнем со словарей.
[**соответствовать**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
***нсв.** чему.* Быть, находиться в соответствии с чем-либо, отвечать чему-либо. *Не соответствовать занимаемой должности. Сведения соответствуют действительности. Работа соответствует стремлениям, способностям кого-либо* (БТС);
синонимы: отвечать, согласоваться, идти, **подходить**, приличествовать, совпадать, быть впору, гармонировать (словарь синонимов).

[**подойти**](https://gufo.me/dict/mas/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8), *несов.* **подходить** (МАС)
**6.** Оказаться **соответствующим** чему-либо, годным, приемлемым для кого-либо, чего-либо.
*Как ты думаешь, кремовый воротничок к этому платью подойдет?* (А. Софронов. Московский характер); *Я на флот служить пойду, если ростом подойду* (С. Михалков. Дядя Степа).

Продолжим, порассуждаем, обратим внимание на управление. Из первой ссылки видно, что *подходить* является синонимом глагола *соответствовать*. А из МАС я выбрала именно то значение, в котором эти слова взаимозаменяемы (так как слово *подойти* многозначно).

Цена нефти соответствует текущей ситуации. = Цена нефти подходит для текущей ситуации.
Не соответствует занимаемой должности. = Не подходит для занимаемой должности.
Воротничок этому платью соответствует? = Воротничок к этому платью подходит?

Comment: Спорно, всё-таки ракурс разный. У синонимов ракурс обычно совпадает. В третьем примере да, ощущается синонимичность. Как видим, эти три словарных определения не подходят ко всем случаям, иногда значение "быть соответствующим", а иногда — "быть годным, приемлемым". В остальных двух примерах больше второе. Возможно, что синоним, но не всегда. Примеры с несовпадением ракурса: *быстрый* и *активный*; *добрый* и *безгрешный*.